# Why are there small dots on bokeh circles when I zoom in all the way?

Tags: artifacts, spots

I just took a photo with manual focus and blurred as much as I could a light, but instead of getting a uniform colour, there are dots, like dust :

[image]

Do you know what's causing the darker dots?

Comment: I take it this is a 1:1 crop from a small portion of the frame?

Comment: @mattdm yes, this is a cropped photo (that has by the way also been zoomed with a lens), why ?

Comment: Because it's a big difference whether this is a pixel-peeping magnified view or the whole scene.

Comment: Other information that would be useful: RAW or JPEG from the camera? If RAW, processed with what software?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking at the pixel level, these artifacts are too small to be dust. It's also unlikely that dust would be outlined sharply when you're using a wide aperture.

I think it's most likely that they are random shot noise combined with demosaicing artifacts, possibly then also smoothed out by denoising.

Comment: I don't think it's noise since it's always there (and position varies with lens zoom).

Comment: Can you post an example of that?